# merge duplicate rows by adding a column 'count'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge duplicate rows by adding a new column 'count'

[image: Initial Data frame]

Final dataframe that I want

[image: Final Dataframe that I want]

rows can be in any order

Comment: Check second answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df["count"] = 1
df = df.groupby(["user_id", "item_id", "total"])["count"].count().reset_index()
```

Comment: It removes rows as i want but not working for the next column 'count' that i want to add

Comment: @RahulChaudhary Please upvote if helped